# What is the best way to load a 20 GB csv file into R?

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a data set of 20 GB and I have to work with it in R. Now, I have read several articles how to handle this but I have no idea what the best and most efficient way is to read 20 GB of data in R.

Important to mention is that I do not need all the data, so I have to filter/clean the data before I am going to proceed with building my model.

Is it an idea to read the data set into R with Chunks? And what is the best way to read data into Chunks into R?

I hope that someone can help me out.

Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Unless your computer has 20GB of RAM to spare, you can't do this.

Comment: Hi Tim, I only have 8 GB of RAM. But I have read that something like this is possible, like reading in for example 10,000 rows and then cleaning it and then read the next 10,000 rows etc.

Comment: Yes that is possible.  I think R has a `readLines()` function which might help you.

Comment: Is it possible that someone provides some code for this?

Comment: You can run bigger data with the ``memory.limit()`` function too. It will run a part of the data on your HDD/SSD if your too short on RAM. The ``nrows`` argument in the ``read.csv()`` function allow you to choose the number of line to read if you only need a sample. Otherwise you can clean the data too which is probably the best solution here.

Comment: @MatthijsEigenhuis As an example you could do : ``read.csv("file = C:\Path\To\YourFile.csv", nrows = 10000)``. This will only return the 10 000 first lines.

Comment: But then, I want to read the second part, read.csv("file = C:\Path\To\YourFile.csv", ,skip =10000, nrows = 10000), and it would scan again the whole file right? is there a solution with a pointer or something like that, that R knows that it has to start at 10000?

Comment: Yes you have the ``skip`` argument where you specify R how much rows you want to skip. So you could do : ``read.csv("file = C:\Path\To\YourFile.csv", nrows = 10000, skip = 10000)``

Comment: Thanks a lot Gainz! Last question, is it not better to use 'fread' for this (this should be faster), and to program a for loop for example over it ?

Comment: You could definitively program a script with some for loop. Also the ``fread()`` function from the ``data.table`` package is super fast, but I had some problems making it read ``.csv`` files sometimes. I suggest you try it on your data if it doesn't work simply use ``read.csv()`` like in my example.

Comment: You can also give the "vroom" package a try: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/ it works quite well, although I never tried with a 20Gb file. Worth trying though! Some benchmarks: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html

Comment: Loading a 20gb file into R is crazyness, R is not built for files that big. You would be much better off loading the file into a database and then using `dbplyr` for the wrangling

Comment: Not everything should be done in R. You could either load the data into a SQL database or use command line tools (grep/awk) to reduce the size of your CSV before reading in. `read.csv.sql` allows you to read the CSV into a SQLlite database and run queries on it returning the result to R.

Comment: thanks a lot, what kind of data base do you think of? @Shinobi_Atobe

Comment: You can get $500 free credit when you slight up to Google cloud. You can use big query then to upload. Check out the r package `bigrquery`

Answer (score 2):

You could load the data in different parts. Just like you suggest in your comment you could select 10 000 rows and then another 10 000 and so on.

Since you are working with .csv files, I suggest you use the `read.csv()` function.

Example :

`data <- read.csv("file = C:\Path\To\YourFile.csv", nrows = 10000, skip = 10000)`

**nrows** = the number of rows you want R to read.

**skip** = the number of rows you want R to skip.

Answer (score 0):

The `fread` function in the `data.table` package is probably your best bet for an off the shelf function in terms of speed and efficiency. Like was mentioned previously, you can still include the `nrows` and `skip` arguments to read the data in pieces.